# Java - ListIterator and hasNext

Tags: java, list, iterator

I'm studying Java, and I've a problem with `ListIterator`. I've a List with these characters: b u o n g i o r n o. My code returns "buongiorno", while I was expecting it to print "buongiorn", without the trailing "o". I was expecting this because of the `hasNext()` function. My code uses recursion. Can you explain to me the reason?

```
public static String creaStringa(List<Character> lista) {
    System.out.println(lista.size());
    ListIterator<Character> it = lista.listIterator();
    return ricCrea(it);
}


public static String ricCrea(ListIterator<Character> it) {
    if(!(it.hasNext())) {
        return "";
    else
        return String.valueOf(it.next()) +ricCrea(it);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

It would be more clear if the list had only one element, lets say "b". `hasNext()` would actually return true, and `next()` would read it and the iteration would end after that.

**Explanation:**

If you call `Iterator<Object> it= list.iterator()` on any non-empty list (even if it has only one element), you get `true` for calling the `hasNext()`. That is because the iterator is initialized BEFORE the first element:

```
  b u n g i o r n o
 ^
 i - iterator
```

And when you call `next()` it does two things:

- it reads the element in front of the iterator,
- moves the iterator just after the element that has been just read, and before the next one.

In your example - it prints "b" and stops before the "u":

```
  b u n g i o r n o 
   ^
   i
```

And just before the end:

```
  b u n g i o r n o
                 ^
                 i
```

It actually has the next value - "o". Calling the `next()` will read that value and jump after the `o`. There are no more elements. `hasNext()` will show false, and calling `next()` will result in an exception.

**Technical details:**

Basic idea how iterator is implemented is this:
 - when the `Iterator` is created by calling the `iterator()` on a `List`, its inner variable called `next` is pointing to the first element of the list.
 - `hasNext()` just checks whether the `next` is `!= null`.
 - `next()` returns `next` and sets the `next` to show the next element.

This is `java.util.ArrayList` Iterator (with some details omitted):

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
     return new Itr();
}

private class Itr implements Iterator<E> {
     int cursor;       // index of next element to return
     int lastRet = -1; // index of last element returned; -1 if no such
     int expectedModCount = modCount;

     public boolean hasNext() {
         return cursor != size;
     }

     public E next() {
         checkForComodification();
         int i = cursor;
         Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;
         cursor = i + 1;
         return (E) elementData[lastRet = i];
     }

 }
```

Comment: Although, it's easier to understand how Iterator works by picturing it like this; it's incorrect. Programmatically, you can't point your cursor between two elements because it's implemented as just an index.

Comment: `T next` points to an element, and `hasNext()` checks whether `next != null`, yadda, yadda, we know all about it, but this is for better understanding of the concept.

Answer (score 1):

The `ListIterator.hasNext()` would return `true` for the last "o" character as well (just like every other character). Hence, the `else` would get executed too. It's only after the last "o" has been fetched that `hasNext()` would return false (since it has gone past all the elements now).

The thing to note here is that `hasNext()` only checks if something else is still available for return on the `next()` call. It doesn't fetch or skip it by itself.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply. In my italian book it is written "next returnes the values of the position of the iteretor, then shift the iterator to the next position". Is it right?

Comment: Just a slight correction: "`next()` returns the **value at the current position** of the Iterator, then shifts the iterator to the next position".

Answer (score 1):

The iterator starts "pointing" to the item before the first one.

next() makes the iterator point to the next item and return it.

So you are actually iterating through the whole list.

This is to enable the following syntax when iterating:

```
while (it.hasNext())
{
   ItemClass itemValue = it.next();
   // do something with the value
}
```

an the same syntax can be used even if the iterator is empty.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply. In my italian book it is written "next returnes the values of the position of the iteretor, then shift the iterator to the next position". So it's wrong?

Comment: See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html " Next: Returns the next element in the iteration."

Comment: The thing with iterator is that conceptually it does not point to anything. There is only an ordered set of items and you can get the next one and know whether there are more.

Comment: You can think of it as: starts before the first item -> next increases pointer and then returns value or starts at first item -> next returns and then increases pointer. In either case hasNext is false only when the whole list has been iterated.

Answer (score 0):

When the iterator is at the last 'n' and `ricCrea` is called, then `hasNext` will return `true` and `next` will return 'o'.

So you may want to write something like:

```
public static String ricCrea(ListIterator<Character> it) {
    if (it.hasNext()) {
        Character c = it.next();
        if (it.hasNext()) {
            return c + ricCrea(it);
        }
    }
    return "";
 }
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply. In my italian book it is written "next returnes the values of the position of the iteretor, then shift the iterator to the next position". Is it right?

Comment: @DanieleImpagliazzo No. It returns the next value after the current position.

Answer (score 0):

hasnext() method just lets you know if there is a character left out in the list or not. next() is the method that gets you the value of the character. So, hasnext() doesn't increment the position of the iterator. It just tells whether there is any element in the next position or not, based on which you can call next() or do the desired operation.